# Installation of tensorflow of version =>2.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, cython

I have:
Python 3.7.2
Cython 0.29.23.

I am upgrading the version of tensorflow from 1.14.0 to a value greater than or equal to 2.2 in Anaconda navigator's environment "tsa_course", but I am getting this error:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

- argon2-cffi -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
- bleach -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
- grpcio -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
- h5py -> python[version='<3']
- html5lib=1.0.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
- jinja2 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
- jupyter_console -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
- keras-applications -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

and the list goes on.......

Can anyone help me update the version of tensorflow.

Comment: Are you using ```conda```? If yes, you could simply try ```conda remove tensorflow``` and then install the right version.

Comment: Here many packages were updated in Anaconda but, not all of them were compatible with each other. So, You can create a new environment and installed installed all the required packages again. For example `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0`.Thanks!